# How can I make and run a C# application in Navisworks Manage 2023?

Tags: c#, dll, autodesk-navisworks

I want to make a very simple program that I will use in Navisworks Manage 2023 to get the names of all the currently selected elements. I have never ran an external program in Navisworks before so I may be doing something wrong with the building of the .dll file or maybe there is something else I am missing (I have seen some sources saying I need a .xml file and other tutorials I have watched never even mention a .xml file).

Here is my C# source code in question, but I know how to write in C# so I am not sure this is the issue:

```
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api;
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Plugins;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ModelLister
{
    [Plugin("ExportSelectedItems", "YourCompany", ToolTip = "Exports names of selected items to a text file", DisplayName = "Export Selected Items")]

    public class ExportSelectedItems : AddInPlugin
    {
        public override int Execute(params string[] parameters)
        {
            // Get the current selection
            ModelItemCollection selectedItems = Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application.ActiveDocument.CurrentSelection.SelectedItems;

            // Extract names
            List<string> itemNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in selectedItems)
            {
                itemNames.Add(item.DisplayName);
            }

            // Ask user to select file location
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "txt";
            saveFileDialog.AddExtension = true;

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Write names to file
                File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog.FileName, itemNames);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

These are the only errors that are being thrown, but I genuinely don't believe that they are related to me:

Error   NWTreeComboControl, Name='mTreeComboControl'    DropDownWidth   NWRibbonResizeControl.MaxWidth  Double  DropDownWidth property not found on object of type NWTreeComboControl.

Error   NWRibbonTreeCombo   Orientation RibbonItemControl.Orientation, Name='mRibbonItemControl'    Orientation Orientation property not found on object of type NWRibbonTreeCombo.

Error   QuickAccessRedoButton   Current ContentPresenter.NoTarget   Object  Current property not found on object of type QuickAccessRedoButton.

Error   QuickAccessUndoButton   Current ContentPresenter.NoTarget   Object  Current property not found on object of type QuickAccessUndoButton.

Error   SeparatorData   name    TextBlock.Text  String  name property not found on object of type SeparatorData.

Error   SeparatorData   image   Image.Source    ImageSource image property not found on object of type SeparatorData.

Error   SeparatorData   alignment   StackPanel.Tag  Object  alignment property not found on object of type SeparatorData.

These get thrown when I run my program from the built in Debug>Attach to Process thing in Visual Studio Community 2022

I have tried creating a .xml file, I have tried moving the .dll file out of the Plugins folder in Navisworks, I have tried placing the referenced .dll files into the Plugins folder in Navisworks with my .dll file.